# Filter out any value other than a number

Tags: lisp, racket

I am trying to come up with a procedure that filters out any value other than a number. For example:

`'(1 2 (a) 3) => '(1 2 () 3)` or `'(1 2 (a 10 11 (b 2 (c))) 3) => '(1 2 (10 11 (2 ())) 3)`

This is what I have so far but it doesn't really work because it replaces the non numbers with an empty list instead of nothing:

```
(define (filter-numbers lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (if (list? lst)
          (cons
           (filter-numbers (car lst))
           (filter-numbers (cdr lst)))
          (if (number? lst)
              lst
              '())))
  )
```

The procedure outputs the following:

```
> (filter-numbers '(1 2 (a) 3))
'(1 2 (()) 3)
```

instead of: `'(1 2 () 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if an element in a sublist is a number *before* deciding to `cons` it to the output or not. I think it's easier if we restructure the code a bit; also some tips: don't use `list?`, prefer `pair?` as it's faster (unlike `list?` it doesn't have to traverse the whole list). And prefer `cond` instead of nesting `if`s, your code will be easier to read. This is what I mean:

```
(define (filter-numbers lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((not (pair? (car lst)))
         ; check the element while still in a list, if we wait
         ; until we reach an atom it's too late to filter it out
         (if (number? (car lst))
             ; either add the element to the output or skip it
             (cons (car lst) (filter-numbers (cdr lst)))
             (filter-numbers (cdr lst))))
        (else (cons
               (filter-numbers (car lst))
               (filter-numbers (cdr lst))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(filter-numbers '(1 2 (a) 3))
=> (1 2 () 3)
(filter-numbers '(1 2 (a 10 11 (b 2 (c))) 3))
=> '(1 2 (10 11 (2 ())) 3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is awesome:)